# Can I see all files from a specific commit?

Tags: git

I can use `git ls-files` to see **all** files in the project that are tracked by git.

Can I use this command to see *all* files that were present in some specific commit? I mean not those files that were changed at the moment of the commit, but the whole files tree like how it works with `git ls-files`?

Comment: AFAIU no, commit hash refers to a state of tree where you have all files. But if you want to get a list of touched files by commit you might start from `git diff --stat` (I believe there is more suitable commands for that)

Comment: how about `git checkout revision` , then `git ls-files` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much simpler than the temporary index method, but the output format differs depending on options:

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r <commit>
```